# iterate through json_encode array in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

i'm having problem on how to iterate in the array in json_encode.

I do ajax POST, in where i have a looping code that do "array push" in jQuery, something like this:

```
 $(this).closest('tr.header').nextUntil('.header').each(function(){
            i++;
            var forms="<form method='POST'>"+$(this).html()+'</form>';
            data.push($(forms).serializeArray());           
         });
```

So when i pass this to my controller/ other page, i do this:

```
  $dataList = json_encode($this->input->post("form"));  

  echo $dataList ;
```

And the output is:

```
 [
   [{"name":"category_1", "values":"packages"},
    {"name":"PK_1", "values": "1"}
   ],
   [{"name":"category_2", "value":"products"},
    {"name":"PK_2", "value": "3"}
   ]
 ]
```

I have tried to do :

```
  foreach ($dataList as $data) {                            
     echo $data . "\n";                                 
  }
```

But only give me error on foreach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to decode that: use json_decode($dataList)

Comment: In my 2nd statement, i already did the json_encode.

Comment: Sorry for that. Decode is what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_decode()`function to get your data as an array then foreach your data.

```
  $a = '[
    [{"name":"category_1", "values":"packages"},
     {"name":"PK_1", "values": "1"}
    ],
    [{"name":"category_2", "value":"products"},
     {"name":"PK_2", "value": "3"}
    ]
  ]';
    echo '<pre>';
    $res = json_decode($a, true);

    $newArr = [];
    foreach($res as $data => $val)
    {
       foreach($val as $key2 => $val2)
       {
           $newArr[] = $val2;
       }
    }

    foreach($newArr as $key => $val)
    {
        echo 'Name = ' . $val['name'] . ' Values = ' . $val['value'] . '<br/>';
    }
```

Comment: Oh. My bad. Looks okay now . then how can i go through each items? Like the category_1, PK_1 >?

Comment: Can I see the print_r($data)?

Comment: Array
(
 [0]=>Array
 (
  [name]=>category_1
  [value]=>packages
 )
 [1]=>Array
 (
  [name]=>PK_1
  [value]=>1
 )
)

Array
(
 [0]=>Array
 (
  [name]=>category_2
  [value]=>product
 )
 [1]=>Array
 (
  [name]=>PK_2
  [value]=>2
 )
)

Comment: Yup. This solve my problem. Thank you :) But the last line ' Values =' .$val['values'] . Should only $val['value'] ;

Answer (score 1):

for `array` output you need to decode it with `json_decode()`

here is sample code.

```
$encode_data = '[[{"name":"category_1", "values":"packages"},{"name":"PK_1", "values": "1"}],[{"name":"category_2", "value":"products"},{"name":"PK_2", "value": "3"}]]';

$dataAr = json_decode($encode_data , true);


foreach($dataAr as $data)
{   
    foreach($data as $value){
        $value=array_values($value);
        echo 'name => ' .$value[0] . ' value => ' .$value[1];
        echo "<br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: How can i get through item, for example just the "category"?

Comment: @user3651476 what you want to get name or value ??

Comment: Both, cause i need this to be inserted in database. Thanks

Comment: Im having the problem of "trying to get property of non-object".

Answer (score 1):

Just decode the string and loop through the created array.

```
  <?php 
$a = '[
    [{"name":"category_1", "values":"packages"},
     {"name":"PK_1", "values": "1"}
    ],
    [{"name":"category_2", "value":"products"},
     {"name":"PK_2", "value": "3"}
    ]
  ]';
    echo '<pre>';
    $res = json_decode($a, true);

    $newArr = array();
    foreach($res as $data => $val)
    {

        foreach($val as $k=>$value){
            $value=array_values($value);
          echo 'Name => ' . $value[0] . ' Value => ' . $value[1] . '<br/>';
        }

    }


?>
```